# MongoDB: Save files on memory instead of disk

Tags: mongodb, memcached, redis

Can I use MongoDB like Redis or Memcache?

My goal is to have everything in memory and make it faster to access. We already use MongoDB but we need to improve the speed of reads.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Have you verified that all your time-critical queries are using indexes?

Comment: MongoDB makes use of available memory, so if your indexes and dataset don't fit in memory one answer would be "get more RAM".  It would be more useful if you could post an example of a specific read query that is not performant, as your speed issue may be related to approach rather than resource.

Answer (score 2):

You can't force mongodb to keep everything in RAM. It will keep hot and recently used data in RAM and page out the rest. If you can't afford to suffer a delay on page fault, then use redis/memcached.

Or, alternatively, you can put mongodb's data dir on a ram disk. That will effectively keep everything in memory, but you'll duplicate some data (one copy on ram disk, another - in memory mapped files in mongo).

Comment: http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/whats-new-mongodb-30-part-3-performance-efficiency-gains-new-storage-architecture There is a new experimental feature for in memory storage.

Comment: @dedunumax: this is great news. Someday, mongodb might even be usable in real-world apps :)